# Calculating the limit of complex norm squared

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g(z)= z \overline{z}$. Prove that $g^\prime(z_0)$ exists $\iff z_0 = 0$.

I already proved $(\Leftarrow)$, how do I do the forward direction $(\Rightarrow)$? I tried using the definition of the complex derivative:

Suppose $g^\prime(z_0)$ exists. Then $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}= \frac{\left|z \right|^2- \left|z_0 \right|^2}{z-z_0}$ exists. I know that this should somehow reduce to $\overline{z}$, which should show that $z_0=0$, but I am having trouble with the intermediate steps here. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $z_0\ne0$, it helps if you write the quotient this way:
$$
\frac{|z_0+h|^2-|z_0|^2}h=\frac{2\text{Re}\,\overline{z_0}h+|h|^2}{h}.
$$
The term $|h|^2/h$ will go to zero no matter what, so we focus on $\frac{2\text{Re}\,\overline{z_0}h}{h}$.

When $h=itz_0$, $t>0$, $$\frac{2\text{Re}\,\overline{z_0}h}{h}=0.$$ If $h=tz_0$ for $t>0$, 
$$
\frac{2\text{Re}\,\overline{z_0}h}{h}=2\frac{|z_0|}{z_0}\ne0.
$$
So the limit does not exist.

Comment: Could we do a similar trick for the definition $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: How did you get the quotient $\frac{\left|z \right|^2-\left|z_0 \right|^2}{z-z_0}$ into the form $\frac{\left|z_0+ h \right|^2- \left|z_0 \right|^2}{h}$?

Comment: You let $h=z-z_0$.

Comment: Great! :) $\ \ $

Comment: Does $\text{Re } \overline{z_0} = x_0$ if $\overline{z_0} = x_0-iy_0$? I'm having a little trouble following the computation

Comment: @George: yes. $\text{Re}\,z=(z+\overline z)/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Prove that $f(z) = \bar z$ is not differentiable at any $z_0 \neq 0$ by writing, for $z_0 \neq 0$,

$$\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{\bar z - \bar z_0}{z - z_0} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0, y_0)} \frac{((x -x_0)- i(y-y_0))^2}{(x-x_0)^2 + (y -y_0)^2}$$

where $z = x+ iy$ and $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$, then find the limit over each path: $x = x_0$ and $y=y_0$.

- If $z \mapsto z\bar z$ is differentiable at $z_0 \neq 0$, then so is $z \mapsto \bar z$.

Answer (score 1):

Proof ad absurdum. If deravative exist, limit **must be independent** of path by which you approach to $z_0$. If $z_0\ne0$ the limit will depent of parallel real or imaginary axis you approach to $z_0$...thus limit depends upon path and derevative not exist